# SSMS - Give Myself Execute Plan Power

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I was told I have SysAdmin power on the server, but when I go to run a query and look at the execution plan, I am unable to.

Would it be possible to give myself execute plan powers? If so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114786/allowing-non-sysadmin-users-to-see-sql-server-execution-plans

Comment: If you are a sysadmin role member, you have SHOWPLAN permission. Permissions are not checked for sysadmin role members.

Comment: "I was told..." - trust, but verify. That is, what do sys.user_token and sys.login_token say? Showplan permission is a database-level permission so you can also check sys.fn_my_permissions for the database in question.